# Double HTTP Authorization

Tags: php, http, authorization

I am currently working on a project that I've decided to go with basic HTTP authorization at the admin area for simplicity, however the company I'm working for already has HTTP authorization on their staging server and I was wondering if it is possible to have double HTTP authorization? Looking at the headers I thought that the `realm` part is what defines where the user is authorized but if I implement it like that currently, after I enter my credentials for the staging server and then on my inner authorization something that looks like an infinite loop starts, the page never loads.

Is this possible at all or is there some kind of error in my code?

The code is pretty basic stuff:

```
function require_auth() {

    if (!isset($_SESSION['auth'])) {

        if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] === '...' && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] === '...') {
            return $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
        } else {
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="uniquerealm"');
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        }


        exit('403 access denied');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HTTP request passes through multiple servers, such as a reverse proxy then an app server, you can use HTTP Basic Auth on each server provided that you accept the same username and password and report the same realm on each server that checks the auth.  The `realm` partitions the URL space that the user sees into different areas, rather than identifying a particular server as I think your question is implying.  I've successfully implemented Basic Auth in multiple layers in the past when all 3 pieces matched between servers.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, there are 2 layers of credentials that I'm trying to pass. Apparently that is not possible, is what I'm understanding from your answer, is that correct?

Comment: It might be possible - it depends on what your constraints are.  I was answering for a scenario where the two layers could configured the same.  Other approaches would work if you are OK with the user entering one username and password for server #1, and then server #1 converting the request to use a different username and password before sending it to server #2 (the user would not know the second username and password in this case).  On the other hand, if you want the user to directly enter the username and password for each layer using Basic Auth, I don't have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Using python httpx_auth, I successfully passed through two Basic HTTP Authentication with different credentials:

```
import httpx
from httpx_auth import Basic
with httpx.Client() as client:
    a= client.get('https://example.com', auth=Basic('user1', 'password1') + Basic('user2','password2'))
```